# Cannot access companion object but can instantiate class

Tags: scala, companion-object

I have the following source code:

```
abstract class Foo{
}
object Foo{
    def foo(f : String) = println(f)
}
object Tester extends App{
    class Bar extends Foo
    val b = new Bar()
    Bar.foo("bar")
}
```

When I try to run this with sbt I get the error:

```
Foo.scala:9:5: not found: value Bar
[error]     Bar.foo("bar") // this line won't compile...
[error]     ^
[error] one error found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 0 s, completed Mar 12, 2020 10:29:49 AM
```

Why can't I refer to Bar even though I have declared it as a class in the app.

Comment: `foo` exists in the `Foo` **object** not in the `Foo` **class**, thus extending it doesn't will be inherited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why can't I refer to Bar even though I have declared it as a class in the app.

You are not referring to it as a class. You are referring to an *object* named `Bar`. There is no such object in scope.

Comment: Thanks, Jorg! I didn't realize that by creating a companion object for an abstract class then extending the abstract class that you don't automatically inherit the companion object as well. I got around this by making the methods that I wanted to inherit from the companion object to the abstract class (object Foo) a trait instead (trait FooTrait) then I made the companion object for Bar extend FooTrait.

Answer (score 0):

`object Foo` is not the companion object of `class Bar` even though `Bar` extends `class Foo`, for example

```
abstract class Foo {
  Foo.foo("woohoo") // OK
}
object Foo {
  private def foo(f : String) = println(f)
}
class Bar extends Foo {
  Foo.foo("woohoo") // Error
}
```

Companion object has to have the **same** name as the corresponding class.